# Adobe Reader not respecting viewing settings - Why?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

When I click on a document or open a PDF from a web page, the PDF does not respect the page-override settings.

I am running Adobe 10.1.9.22 and I have set the preferences as such:

```
Edit->Preferences->Page Display->Page Display:Single Page, Zoom:100%
```

and

```
Edit->Preferences->Accessibility->Override Page Display->Always Use Page Layout Style:Single Page, Always Use Zoom Setting: 100%
```

Is there something else I am missing?  The settings are not respected whether I view a PDF via local file or via url....

Thanks

Comment: I don't know any solution to this, but it annoys me too. Adobe Reader 11.0.07 has the same problem, and Google search results suggest it's been like this since at least version 9.3.0, but older versions used to respect the preferences.

Comment: @ScottLeis - I tried Foxit Reader and it operates only slightly better.  It respects the settings for local files, but does not for web files - which of course is the issue for my users.